# Duplicate libraries in two different project modules

Tags: android, cordova, salesforce, retrofit, okhttp

I have project with two modules.
I'm using **SalesforceSDK** which is included as separate module and inside **SalesforceSDK** I have **Cordova** which is using `okhttp`.
In second module I have retrofit library which is using `okhttp` too and when I try to build the project I get

> duplicate dex files error

I tried to delete `okhttp` dependency from **SalesforceSDK** and include it from my second module but I'm getting

> symbols not found error

Only thing left to do is to include `okhttp` as different module but before I do that I want to ask you if there is another way to fix this problem ?

## EDIT:

I tried solution proposed by Aayushi but still I get errors :

> Error:Execution failed for task
> ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
>
> > java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/squareup/okhttp/Address.class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using android studio no need to delete you can use both library

just use

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
     ...
      multiDexEnabled = true
  }
}
```

using this statement is also required

```
dependencies 
{
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: I tried it and got error again.For more informations check my edit

Comment: If then also you are getting error then you also add  compile('nameoflibrary') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v7'
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }

Comment: also   packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [jarjar](https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/), which can let you use one version of OkHttp in one place and another somewhere else.

There are other similar tools (shade), and most of ‘em will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I also have another solution for this issue.
Firstly, I run this command line:
[image]

and this is result:

[image]

I saw that Paypal also use okhttp library.So, I added this line to gradlew:

```
compile('com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.13.3')
        {
            exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
        }
```

And It aslo works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by following this - https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes

In my case, cordova-android-3.3.0.jar was a dependency in 2 different projects and one of those is a dependency of the other one.